# How to show in a dialog box if an item is already in the listView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an application where users can enter some values in edittexts and see this values in a  listview. The values are stored using SQLite. Everything works fine till now. What I want is to have a dialog box which appears when the user tries to add values which already exist in the database. Can anyone helping me coding an example this way? Thanks a lot !

**Absente:**

```
package ro.radioamatori;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class Absente extends Activity {

    private DbHelper_absente mHelpera;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    TextView n;




    private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_lName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> d = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> stime = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> etime = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> freq = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mode = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> station = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> loc = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> tqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> comm = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ListView userLista;
    private AlertDialog.Builder build;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.absente_listview);

        userLista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lista);




        TextView getTotalCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        getTotalCount.setText("Total conne"+userLista.getCount());

        mHelpera = new DbHelper_absente(this);

        //add new record
        findViewById(R.id.btnAdda).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adauga_absente.class);
                i.putExtra("update", false);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //click to update data
        userLista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adauga_absente.class);
                i.putExtra("Fname", user_fName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("Lname", user_lName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", d.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", stime.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", etime.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", freq.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", mode.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", station.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", loc.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", tqsl.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", mqsl.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", comm.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("update", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //long click to delete data
        userLista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    final int arg2, long arg3) {

                build = new AlertDialog.Builder(Absente.this);
                build.setTitle("Esti sigur ca vrei sa stergi? ");
                build.setMessage("Esti sigur ca vrei sa stergi aceasta inregistrare ?");
                build.setPositiveButton("Da",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(), "Inregistrarea a fost stearsa", 3000).show();

                                dataBase.delete(
                                        DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                                        DbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                                + userId.get(arg2), null);
                                displayData();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                build.setNegativeButton("Nu",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = build.create();
                alert.show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * displays data from SQLite
     */
    private void displayData() {
        dataBase = mHelpera.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

        userId.clear();
        user_fName.clear();
        user_lName.clear();
        d.clear();
        stime.clear();
        etime.clear();
        freq.clear();
        mode.clear();
        station.clear();
        loc.clear();
        tqsl.clear();
        mqsl.clear();
        comm.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));
                user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));
                d.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_D)));
                stime.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_STIME)));
                etime.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ETIME)));
                freq.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FREQ)));
                mode.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MODE)));
                station.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_STATION)));
                loc.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LOC)));
                tqsl.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_TQSL)));
                mqsl.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MQSL)));
                comm.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_COMM)));


            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        NoteAdapter disadpt = new NoteAdapter(Absente.this,userId, user_fName, user_lName, d, stime, etime, freq, mode, station, loc, tqsl, mqsl, comm);
        userLista.setAdapter(disadpt);
        mCursor.close();
    }



}
```

**DBHelper:**

```
package ro.radioamatori;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
    public static final String KEY_D="date";
    public static final String KEY_STIME="stime";
    public static final String KEY_ETIME="etime";
    public static final String KEY_FREQ="freq";
    public static final String KEY_MODE="mode";
    public static final String KEY_STATION="station";
    public static final String KEY_LOC="loc";
    public static final String KEY_TQSL="tqsl";
    public static final String KEY_MQSL="mqsl";
    public static final String KEY_COMM="comm";
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_D+" TEXT, "+KEY_STIME+" TEXT, "+KEY_ETIME+" TEXT, "+KEY_FREQ+" TEXT, "+KEY_MODE+" TEXT, "+KEY_STATION+" TEXT, "+KEY_LOC+" TEXT, "+KEY_TQSL+" TEXT, "+KEY_MQSL+" TEXT, "+KEY_COMM+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

**Adapter:**

```
  package ro.radioamatori;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> id;
        private ArrayList<String> firstName;
        private ArrayList<String> lastName;
        private ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<String> stime = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<String> etime = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<String> freq = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<String> mode = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<String> station = new ArrayList<String>();
        privat

e ArrayList<String> loc = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> tqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> comm = new ArrayList<String>();

    public NoteAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,
            ArrayList<String> fname, ArrayList<String> lname,
            ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> stime,
            ArrayList<String> etime, ArrayList<String> freq,
            ArrayList<String> mode, ArrayList<String> station,
            ArrayList<String> loc, ArrayList<String> tqsl,
            ArrayList<String> mqsl, ArrayList<String> comm) {
        this.mContext = c;

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.date = date;
        this.stime = stime;
        this.etime = etime;
        this.freq = freq;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.station = station;
        this.loc = loc;
        this.tqsl = tqsl;
        this.mqsl = mqsl;
        this.comm = comm;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.note_items, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            mHolder.d = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.d);
            mHolder.st = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.st);
            mHolder.et = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.et);
            mHolder.f = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.f);
            mHolder.m = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.m);
            mHolder.s = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.s);
            mHolder.l = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.l);
            mHolder.tq = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tq);
            mHolder.mq = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.mq);
            mHolder.c = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.c);

            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_id.setText("Connection: " + id.get(pos));
        mHolder.d.setText("Data: " + date.get(pos));
        mHolder.st.setText("Start time: " + stime.get(pos));
        mHolder.et.setText("End time: " + etime.get(pos));
        mHolder.f.setText("Frequency: " + freq.get(pos));
        mHolder.m.setText("Mode: " + mode.get(pos));
        mHolder.s.setText("Station: " + station.get(pos));
        mHolder.l.setText("Location: " + loc.get(pos));
        mHolder.tq.setText("Their QSL: " + tqsl.get(pos));
        mHolder.mq.setText("My QSL: " + mqsl.get(pos));
        mHolder.c.setText("Comment: " + comm.get(pos));


        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView d;
        TextView st;
        TextView et;
        TextView f;
        TextView m;
        TextView s;
        TextView l;
        TextView tq;
        TextView mq;
        TextView c;
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_fName;
        TextView txt_lName;
    }

}
```

**Adauga_absente:**

```
package ro.radioamatori;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Adauga_absente extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button btn_save;
private EditText edit_first,edit_last,d,st,et,f,m,s,l,tq,mq,c;
private DbHelper_absente mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private String id,fname,lname,date,stime,etime,freq,mode,station,loc,tqsl,mqsl,comm;
private boolean isUpdate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adauga_absente);

        btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btna); 
        d=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d);
        st=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.st);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        f=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.f);
        m=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.m);
        s=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.s);
        l=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.l);
        tq=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tq);
        mq=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mq);
        c=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);

        SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat timeF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        String date = dateF.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String time = timeF.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        d.setText(date);
        st.setText(time);


       isUpdate=getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
        if(isUpdate)
        {
            id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
            fname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Fname");
            lname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Lname");
            date=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Date");
            stime=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Stime");
            etime=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Etime");
            freq=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Freq");
            mode=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Mode");
            station=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Station");
            loc=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Loc");
            tqsl=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Tqsl");
            mqsl=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Mqsl");
            comm=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Comm");
            edit_first.setText(fname);
            edit_last.setText(lname);
            d.setText(date);
            st.setText(stime);
            et.setText(etime);
            f.setText(freq);
            m.setText(mode);
            s.setText(station);
            l.setText(loc);
            tq.setText(tqsl);
            mq.setText(mqsl);
            c.setText(comm);


        }

         btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);

         mHelper=new DbHelper_absente(this);

    }

    // saveButton click event 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fname=edit_first.getText().toString().trim();
        lname=edit_last.getText().toString().trim();
        date=d.getText().toString().trim();
        stime=st.getText().toString().trim();
        etime=et.getText().toString().trim();
        freq=f.getText().toString().trim();
        mode=m.getText().toString().trim();
        station=s.getText().toString().trim();
        loc=l.getText().toString().trim();
        tqsl=tq.getText().toString().trim();
        mqsl=mq.getText().toString().trim();
        comm=c.getText().toString().trim();
        if(fname.length()>0 && lname.length()>0 && date.length()>0 && stime.length()>0 && etime.length()>0 && freq.length()>0 && mode.length()>0 && station.length()>0 && loc.length()>0 && tqsl.length()>0 && mqsl.length()>0 && comm.length()>0)
        {
            saveData();
        }
        else
        {


        }



    }

    /**
     * save data into SQLite
     */
    private void saveData(){
        dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,fname);
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,lname );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_D,date );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_STIME,stime );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_ETIME,etime );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FREQ,freq );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_MODE,mode );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_STATION,station );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LOC,loc );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_TQSL,tqsl );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_MQSL,mqsl );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_COMM,comm );


        System.out.println("");
        if(isUpdate)
        {    
            //update database with new data 
            dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //insert data into database
            dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        //close database
        dataBase.close();
        finish();


    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you are calling `putExtra()` multiple times with the `"date"` key. This will overwrite previous data values.

Comment: Also is you should look at `CursorAdapter` and its derived classes. They do a lo of the work for you and can minimize the amount of code you have.

Comment: As for your question, you could add a UNIQUE constraint to the table which will cause `insert()` to throw an exception when the user tries to add duplicated data. Then you just catch this exception and display your dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write following method in class DbHelper in your case to fetch all data from sqlite in  List

```
// Getting All Contacts
        public List<DataOfUser> getAllContacts() {
            List<DataOfUser> dist = new ArrayList<DataOfUser>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + ITEM.TABLE_DATA;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DataOfUser contact = new DataOfUser();
                    contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    contact.setD(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setDate(cursor.getString(2));


                    dist.add(contact);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                  //
            }

            // return contact list
            return dist;
        }


//Ii is class with public getters and setters to access data    from sqlite.change according to your need   


public class DataOfUser {

    int _id;
    String _data;
    String _date;

    // Empty constructor
    public DataOfUser(){

    }


    // constructor

    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getD(){
        return this._data;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setD(String s){
        this._data = s;
    }
    //
    public void setDate(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         this._date = string;
    }

   public String getDate(){
            return this._date ;
        }

}




//the code below  is just example to get idea to check same value don't  copy paste it
//code to check already exist value as follows
//List<DataOfUser> dataofuse=new ArrayList<DataOfUser>(); create List<DataOfUser> of  in your code for getting data from sqlite
dataofuse = dbHelper.getAllContacts(); 




                if(dataofuse!=null)

                {            
                     //imp


                            for (DataOfUser dataOfUser2 : dataofuse) {
                            //  (dataOfUser2.getD(),dataOfUser2.getDate(),dataOfUser2.getID())  to get the data                
                                 if(//compare data from edittext and fetch data according to above line is same then)
                                 break;
                            }

                            //write code to show dialog or toast here
                }
```

Comment: `//code to check already exist value as follows
//List<DataOfUser> dataofuse=new ArrayList<DataOfUser>(); create List<DataOfUser> of  in your code for getting data from sqlite
dataofuse = dbHelper.getAllContacts(); `
.. Starting from here there is syntax mistakes and I can't understand what u did. + this error: `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` here: for `(DataOfUser dataOfUser2 : dataofuse) {` . Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: hey just dont copy paste the last code.Create List<DataOfUser> dataofuse=new ArrayList<DataOfUser>();  to get data from method List<DataOfUser> getAllContacts().Before displaying ListView try to check same value by iterating over arraylist and then show dialog accordingly

Comment: You lost me. Can you example this to me too, please?

Comment: Ok. So. What should I do next?

Comment: getAllContacts() is going to return you the ArrayList<DataOfUser>,so you must create array list to get the data from method and then you will have arraylist with data,so use that list ,iterate over it to find does it contain any  value which is same to value you fetch from editext and if so break the loop and show the dialog and if not  then simply insert in data in database and refresh the ListView